# The same Moq SetupSequence is being used for different objects

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, rhino-mocks

### Edit: Solved

The code is actually fine. Actually the method being evaluated actually is called more than once. But then Rhino Mocks `Repeat.Once()` don't show proper behavior...

I'm migrating from RhinoMocks to Moq and I'm not being able to make Moq works properly using `mock.SetupSequence(...).Returns(...).Throws(...)`.

I have some tests using nUnit's `TestCaseSource`.

In RhinoMocks there was some code that used a `Stub` call, with `Repeat.Once()`. That worked fine. But now I migrated to Moq and did the `SetupSequence` written above. Every time a new object is create in the `SetUp` method, but I've keep getting the exception.

TestCaseSource:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> SettingsTestCases
{
    get
    {
        // Null Settings
        yield return new TestCaseData(null);

        // Null Acquisition
        yield return new TestCaseData(new Settings(null, new Optics()));

        // Null Optics
        yield return new TestCaseData(new Settings(new Acquisition(), null));
    }
}
```

The SetUp:

```
private Mock<ISample> foo;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
}
```

The Test:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(SettingsTestCases))]
public void PerformTest(Settings settings)
{
    //THESE RHINO MOCKS LINES WORKS
    //foo.Stub(x => x.GetSettings(ExperimentId.)).Return(settings);
    //foo.Expect(x => x.Carrier).Return("Type1").Repeat.Once();

    //IN MOQ, ALWAYS GET THE EXCEPTION
    foo.Setup(x => x.GetSettings(Experiment.Id)).Returns(settings);
    foo.SetupSequence(x => x.Carrier)
        .Returns("Type1")
        .Throws(new Exception("Called too many times"));
    { do asserts here }
}
```

I've noticed that before each time the test runs (3 times, because of the TestCaseSource), it always hit the `SetUp` and create a new instance of `Mock<IFoo>`. So, for each test we have a new `foo` every time, but in the end it seems that the `SetupSequence` calls are shared between the 3 instances because I've got the exception, <del>but I'm sure that it is called only once each test.</del> Rhino Mocks `Repeat.Once()` is working good and seems to refer only for one particular instance.

Could I write the code in a different way, in order to achieve the same response given by the old code (Rhino Mocks)?

Comment: It is bit awkward to throw exception. I think you should use `Verify` method with `Times.Once` instead of `SetupSequence` and throw exception...

Comment: I've tried that. The thing is I need return "Type1" only the first time. The other calls should be anything different. So, actually I've found that I should use SetupSequence(...).Returns(...) without any throw. The number of calls doesn't matter. I just can't figure out why the Rhino Mocks pass this... 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error. Actually during the assert part someone put other calls to `GetSettings` Method, so this would obviously throw errors if only one call was expected.
(So I was sure about something wrong. Shame on me!)

The logic behind is: The first call should return "Type1" and the rest should return something else.

This raise another question: Rhino Mocks `Repeat.Once()` was failing, then? It pass even with more than one call.